# Get inner text and split it. Javascript problems using innerHTML and split

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, innerhtml

Having the next simple html code:

```
<div id="content">
This is a test
</div>
```

I don't understad why this is OK:

```
$(function(){
text = 'this is a text';
word = text.split(' ');
alert(word[1])
})
```

but this is not:

```
$(function(){
text = $('#content').text();
word = text.split(' ');
alert(word[1])
})
```

Jquery or native javascript, the problem is the same. I expect an alert with the same word in both cases, but only occurs in the first one. Where is my mistake?

Here is my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/bbtdf/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (You need to trim the text)

```
$(function(){
    var text = $.trim($('#content').text()),
    word = text.split(' ');
    alert(word[1])
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bbtdf/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the text/html because they will have spaces before and after the content

```
$(function(){
    var text = $('#content').text(),
        word = $.trim(text).split(' ');
    console.log(word[1])
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TjUXb/)

Else you need to write your html as `<div id="content">This is a test</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
This is a test
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
     text = $('#content').text();
     word = text.split(' ');
     alert(word[1])
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 spaces for indentation in the content. The text function is returning the second space in the alert for this case, so it is seen blank.

Remove the indentation/spaces before the content, you should see the expected result.